# What can the word be…?

Tags: word, visual, rebus

What can the word be…? Can you find out the solution to this puzzle?

[image]

**Explanation to second puzzle:** Use an image editor to get the colors of the boxes in `VXJrbnFycHZ6bnk=`. If the colored box is in the first row, add the first and the last character of the color. If it’s in the second row, subtract them. The result will give you the `n`-th letter of the alphabet.

Comment: Any other hints for row 2 ? what next white box pretend with displayed with 1,4 number with cross line? Do we need to remove 1st and 4th Box to solve that row?

Comment: I made the hint clearer.

Comment: @Lypyrhythm btw you may want to use spoiler block instead of base64 for the hints if it's neat for you, nice puzzle tho :)

Comment: @athin I think the explanation is necessary to solve the second puzzle, so there is no need for the spoiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Row 2, the given hint is:

> Use an image editor to get the colors of the boxes in VXJrbnFycHZ6bnk=. If the colored box is in the first row, add the first and the last character of the color. If it’s in the second row, subtract them. The result will give you the nth letter of the alphabet.

The meaningless part of that means:

> "Hexadecimal", after ROT-13 then base64 encoding

Finding the information we need:

> The colours from left-to-right are #C48A96, #F7CE0A, #BEC6A7, #1DC8B3, #D50914, and #A088FA.

Following the instructions, we get:

> C+6 = 12+6 = 18 = R
>  F-A = 15-10 = 5 = E
>  B-7 = 11-7 = 4 = D
>  1+3 = 4 = D
>  D-4 = 13-4 = 9 = I
>  A+A = 10+10 = 20 = T
>  The colours clue 'REDDIT'.

To finish off:

> The bottom of the image indicates that we remove the first and fourth letters, to get EDIT.

Putting it all together with @Deusovi's information:

> They got it right with the (alternate) answer **CREDITORS**.

Comment: Very good! Accepted it as the best answer.

Comment: @Lypyrhythm Other than you finally spelling it out as a "hint", is there something in the puzzle that at all suggests at the way to decode the second part? If an added hint is effectively required for anyone not inside your head to solve (part of) a puzzle then it's not a "hint", it's an essential part of the puzzle--and in many cases is the only thing preventing your puzzle from being "guess what I want you to do here". That kind of information should be part of the puzzle from the start.

Comment: @Rubio I understand, I fixed it.

Comment: Totally agreed with @Rubio

Answer (score 5):

First row:

> `PODCAST` - `POD` - `AST` ("branch" in German) + `R` (Morse)

Second row:

> ?

Third row:

> `ORS` (Braille)

Based on this, the only reasonable option is

> **CREATORS**. (Or CREDITORS, I suppose, but that seems less likely.)

Comment: Looks good! Can you solve the second row? **Hint:** Concentrate on the boxes’ colors.

Answer (score 1):

### First row

> The icon at the start is apparently for Apple **Podcasts**. The next image is of peas in a **pod**, so we remove that. The next image is a branch and a German flag; the word "branch" in German is "**ast**", so we remove that. The next image is R in Morse code, so we add that. Now we're left with **CSR**.